# How to work on View added outside to the main view of ViewController in Storyboards?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard, xcode6

I have created a registration form and in which user can select his Gender. On tapping the button of Gender, I need to show a custom view. I want to use Storyboard for creating view but I cannot work on that as I cannot see it without adding that on the main View of the View Controller. Please see the image below. I want to keep that view separate from the main view of the View Controller and I will add that view programmatically when user will tap on the gender Button.

[image]

Comment: If you really need to separate your view from view controller then you should put it into xib file and get it programically using `UINib loadNib`. If you want to keep it in current storyboard you should set view as hidden and later just change frame and visibility

Comment: @Szu You are right Szu and I already aware of this idea but I really don't want to do that. I was thinking if Apple allows to add the View outside the main view of UIViewController then it must give the facility/feature to work on that UIView. What is the benefit of just adding the view if you cannot see it. I think its very wrong. It has to be changed and Apple should provide something so that developers can work on that kind of view!

Comment: @Developer you are right. Currently we have to drag this view in main story board and do changes on it again we have to set outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a UIView to the canvas in storyboard, it needs to be contained in a UIViewController.

Your options are:

1) Create a xib file for your UIView subclass and design it there. 
Then import it by calling -loadNibNamed: on the main bundle.

2) Do the design layout programmatically inside your UIView subclass.

3) Add a container view to your main VC and use the view controller it generates to design your gender view. Then you can start with it hidden and show it when the gender button is tapped.

Comment: I am aware of these ways but I was just thinking if I can work apart from these ways but it seems not possible.

Answer (score 0):

• Put it as a subview
• Design it
• Put it back there outside of the view controller